# Is there a way who viewed my profile

Tags: support, user-profiles

Could you tell me there is a way who viewed my profile?

I just want to know if there is no function available, could you consider to implement it?

Comment: Since Stack Exchange does not build social networks I'm sure there will be no such feature implemented. It's quite wasteful of resources too if you'd have to log each profile visit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no function like that available to anyone (moderators included).